# Convert crypto class to async code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, encryption, bluebird, cryptojs

For my app, I will heavily use `ecdh`, `aes` and `ecdsa` for securing the authentication of users and maintaining secure lines.

Current code for [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) is entirely synchronous in nature. I have made a utils folder as follows

```
'use strict'

// Make async later on for performance
// Add bluebird for better error handling
const crypto = require('crypto');

let cipher = {};

cipher.createCipher = (pw) => {
  return crypto.createCipher('aes192', pw);
}

cipher.encryptText = (cipher, plainText, callback) => {
  try {
    if (!callback && !callback instanceof Function) {
      throw new Error("callback must be passed")
    }
    if (!plainText instanceof String) {
      throw new Error("2nd param must be plain text")
    }
    let encrypted = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      var data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        encrypted += data.toString('hex');
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, encrypted);
    });
    cipher.write(plainText);
    cipher.end();
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e, null);
  }
}

cipher.decryptText = (cipher, cipherText, callback) => {

}

module.exports = cipher;
```

In my test class, I am calling the functions as

```
const cipher = require('../components/cipher.js');
cipher.encryptText(cipher.createCipher(key), paramOne, (err, data) => {
  console.log('\n  func 1 \n');
  console.log(data);
})

console.log('break');

cipher.encryptText(cipher.createCipher('1'), 'paramTwo', (err, data) => {
  console.log('\n func 2 \n');
  console.log(data);
})
```

paramOne is around 10-12 lines of text, in an asyc function, the lower function should get executed first. However, that is not the case.

Is there any way in which I can modify my `components/cipher.js` class to covert the encrypting and decryption functions to be truely asynchronous.

Multi authorization attempts will require multi key exchanges which is very expensive cpu usage.

Using tests, I have confirmed that the `encryptText()` function is being called for the second time, only after it has returned a value from its from execution, i.e. it waits until `callback` one is done.

need some advice/ help please guys. TiA

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way in which I can modify my components/cipher.js class
>   to covert the encrypting and decryption functions to be truely
>   asynchronous.

In node.js, the only way to convert a truly synchronous CPU-bound operation to an asynchronous operation is to either invoke it in another process or write/modify native code that can use native threads/processes and hook that into node.js as a module.

So, if you really want to keep it from blocking the main node.js executino thread, you'd have to move it out of the node.js process.  You could startup a group of child processes (probably making them simple http servers would be simplest) and then use a work queue to queue up info for each crypto process.  Each crypto process would just listen for a request to do some crypto work.  Since the request to that child process would be an http request, it would be asynchronous from the main node.js thread.  You could fire up as many crypto processes as you had CPUs (minus one) in your computer.  Or, yo could even use other computers for the crypto processes (that doesn't really matter since you're talking to them with http requests).

There's nothing that says the other servers have to be web servers.  They could be webSocket servers or you could make your own protocol on top of TCP.  I suggested web servers just because they are so simple (just a couple lines of code in node.js) and they are easy to scale.

One simple idea might be to create a clustered crypto http server.  Then, you could just blindly make requests of it and the nodejs clustering would automatically handle the load balancing and scaling for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [@ronomon/crypto-async](https://github.com/ronomon/crypto-async) module. It provides truly asynchronous cipher, hash, and HMAC operations executed in Node's threadpool for multi-core throughput. You can run multiple operations in parallel (up to 4x-8x depending on how many cores your machine has).